# Pacote instalado com npm não está disponível no prompt de comando

Tags: node.js

Eu instalei o `nodejs v0.12.6` em meu computador com `windows` porém tive alguns problemas.

O primeiro achei uma solução na internet bem simples e pensei que tudo fosse funcionar normalmente porém ao tentar instalar algum package, neste caso o [hexo](http://hexo.io) ele instala perfeitamente porém ao tentar rodar o comando ele retorna a seguinte mensagem:

> 'hexo' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Porém ao acessar o diretório do `npm` onde o `hexo` foi instalado, no meu caso `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` e executar o comando que inicializa um blog utilizando o hexo:

```
hexo init blog
```

Dentro deste diretório:

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm>hexo init blog
INFO  Copying data to C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\blog
INFO  You are almost done! Don't forget to run 'npm install' before you start blogging with Hexo!
```

Ele instala e gera os arquivos perfeitamente.

Existe alguma forma de corrigir isto? Pois preciso que ele reconheça o comando independente de qual diretório eu esteja, pois no diretório do `npm` não é um lugar adequado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder acessar de qualquer lugar, você precisaria ter feito uma instalação "global" do módulo:

```
npm install -g hexo
```

Isso funciona se o local onde o npm instala os módulos globais estiver disponível no seu PATH do Windows. Verifique se essa variável de ambiente contém [`C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm\node_modules`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9588052/825789), caso contrário inclua esse valor na lista.

Porém, atenção às [recomendações oficiais sobre quando instalar globalmente](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation):

> 1. Se estiver instalando algo que vai usar ewm seu programa, com `require('whatever')`, instale localmente, na raiz do seu projeto.
> 2. Se estiver instalando algo para usar no shell, na linha de comando, instale globalmente para que os binários sejam colocados num local disponível na sua variável de ambiente PATH.

O seu caso parece mesmo ser o (2).

Comment: Eu havia instalado globalmente anteriormente, removi agora e reinstalei para ver se eu havia esquecido algo mas pelo visto não. Continua não reconhecendo como pode ver na imagem: http://i.imgur.com/tJjgPRA.png mas dentro da pasta do npm funciona corretamente: http://prntscr.com/7pzdmw

Comment: Bem, ao verificar as variáveis de ambiente o caminho onde os módulos ficam instalados não estavam disponíveis. Bastou adicionar o caminho completo `C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm` e funcionou perfeitamente, pois como estava `C:\Program Files\nodejs` não funciona. Por favor, adicione a sua resposta e marcarei como correta e muito obrigado.

Comment: De certa maneira eu já tinha mencionado que o caminho precisava estar no PATH, mas editei pra deixar mais claro.